# LINQ "Where" condition -> change value of property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of meetings, inside which I have another list of attendees.

The model is similar to this:

```
public class Meeting
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

I have list of `Meetings`: `List<Meeting> meetings = GetMeetings();`

Now I want to mask the `Title` of the meetings where one of the users is `bot@domain.com`. I can achieve this in multiple LINQ queries but I am looking for one optimized LINQ query.

Here's what I tried:

```
var maskedMeetings = meetings.Where(x = x.Users.Any(a => a.Email.Equals("bot@domain.com"))); 
meetings = appointments.Except(maskedMeetings).ToList();
maskedMeetings = maskedMeetings.Select(x => { x.Title = "Bot"; return x; }).ToList();
meetings = meetings.Concat(maskedMeetings).ToList();
```

Can anyone help me find an optimized way of writing this query?

Comment: What is sub-optimal about what you have?

Comment: Define "optimized".  Changing four clear, concise lines of working code to one long chain is not "optimized" in my opinion.

Comment: Well I agree, @DStanley I am not quite familiar with performance optimizations for LINQ hence I asked the question :-)

Comment: One of the ways you can try to optimize is to reduce ToList calls where it possible

Comment: You could chain them up together in a single long line, but I don't think there would be considerable benefits as far as processing time or resource usage. IMO keep it readable.

Comment: @COLDTOLD That was my **first** thought too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I read your code right, you are querying for a subset of your items, removing those items from the original list, modifying the items in the subset, and putting the modified items back in the list.  There's no need to go through all of that; just modify the items within the list.

Linq, however, is for *querying*, not *updating*.  To update objects in a collection just use a loop:

```
foreach(var meeting in meetings)
{
    if(meeting.Users.Any(a => a.Email.Equals("bot@domain.com")))
        meeting.Title = "Bot";
}
```

or use Linq to pre-filter the list

```
foreach(var meeting in meetings.Where(x = x.Users.Any(a => a.Email.Equals("bot@domain.com")))
{
    meeting.Title = "Bot";
}
```

Note that the performance will likely not be significantly different between the two

Comment: Thanks @DStanley. If possible can you please tell me which one would perform better and why (even if it;s not significantly different). Just for the sake of knowledge :-)

Comment: The first method would _probably_ have a _very, very slight_ edge in performance just due to the overhead of Linq.  But it's not nearly enough to forego the second option.  Use whichever one makes the most sense to you when you read it.

Comment: Thanks @DStanley :-) It helped me a lot

Comment: this is going to loop the data at least 3 times.

Comment: @MatthewWhited Can you explain how?  From what I can tell each will only "loop" once.

Comment: Because he want's all of the data in one list. I guess your way would loop the data twice but you could do it in a single pass if you replace the title in the select statement.

Comment: No it just loops once. And changing the collection. In the projection is not a good approach. Linq is supposed to be free of side-effects. You could project a collection of _new_ objects but that's not what the original code is doing.

Comment: LINQ is what you use of it.  While the C# syntax is nasty this would be no different than a filtered projection.  The better way would be to create a new immutable value for each changed based on the filter but that can be difficult with complex objects.  Yes, you can look the data to filter then update with the foreach but when you iterate the list late you are doing a second pass over the loop.  Which will have a performance impact.

Comment: @MatthewWhited It is only "looping" once.  `Where` just wraps the collection in an iterator that filters the results as it loops.  The `meetings` collection is only iterated one time.  The performance difference between the two options is negligible.